# Google Docs keyboard shortcut for up and down arrow

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

Google Docs has keyboard shortcuts for right arrow (→) as well as left arrow (←). I was wondering is there any keyboard shortcut for up (↑) and down (↓) arrows. I found that I could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for a list of shortcuts, but to my surprise I did not see the up and down arrow not mentioned there.

Please share if someone knows the shortcut or any method to assign some shortcut to the above keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey after googling a lot a found a solution using Unicode. This worked on my Linux system but I cannot guarantee that it will work on others, but I think hopefully it will work

↑: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then <kbd>2191</kbd>

↓: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then <kbd>2193</kbd>

A list of [Unicode symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)) can be found here for reference

I have got even a simpler method if you use it more often. Click on `Tools → Preferences` then add your custom shortcut.

[image]

Comment: What site did you get these shortcuts from? You may want to link it as a source.

Comment: These are defaults I think @Stevoisiak. Also, note that it's a double dash followed by a > for the arrow. `- - >`

Answer (score 3):

If your computer has a number pad, you could use an [Alt Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) shortcut.
 Here's a list of relevant alt codes via [Useful Shortcuts](https://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/arrow-alt-codes.php).

- ↑: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>
- ↓: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>
- →: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>
- ←: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>

  ---

> ### How To Use Alt Code Characters
>
> 1. Make sure that you switch on the Number Lock on your keyboard.
> 2. Hold down the ALT key (left alt key).
> 3. And type the number of which alt code you want to get.
>
> http://www.alt-codes.net/how_to_use_alt_codes/

Comment: Sorry, this might be out of the domain of the question. But it doesn't work on Linux machines

Comment: Anyways I have found the solution using Unicode 

↑ can be generated by `ctrl+shift+u then 2191` and 

↓ can be generated by `ctrl+shift+u then 2193`

Comment: @JayChakra if that was the solution that worked for you, post it as an answer! Self answering questions is not only allowed, but encouraged.

Comment: As suggested I have answered my question. Thanks for the encouragement

Comment: Note you have to click into a cell in google sheets for this to work (i.e. double click so  you see the flashing line indicating you can start typing into the cell).  If you are just arrowing between cells, hitting the Alt codes will not start entering the special characters into the cell.